# Embed different framework based on build configuration

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, frameworks

I have 4 build configurations:

- Debug
- Release
- WhiteLabelDebug
- WhiteLabelRelease

[image: Configurations]

`Debug` and `Release` should link & embed my custom `LightTheme.framework` and not the `WhiteLabelTheme.framework`.

`WhiteLabelDebug` and `WhiteLabelRelease` should link and embed my custom `WhiteLabelTheme.framework` and not the `LightTheme.framework`.

Both of these frameworks have some custom code, localized strings, colors, fonts, and images. We use a different scheme to build each config and submit it to the App Store as a totally different app. However currently both our branded app, and the white label one have both sets of images, fonts, colors, strings, etc. Which really hurts file size.

I can easily weak link both frameworks into the app target, but I can't figure out how to only embed a framework based on the current configuration.

[image: Embed Frameworks settings]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to your target Build Phases and add `New Run Script Phase` as the last step.

Here’s what the script could look like:

```
if [[ ${CONFIGURATION} == "WhiteLabelRelease" ]]; then
    rm -R "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/LightTheme.framework"
elif [[ ${CONFIGURATION} == "Release" ]]; then
    rm -R "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/WhiteLabelTheme.framework"
fi
```

When building any of your *Release builds (and Archiving for submission), the script will remove a corresponding framework. It will leave them in place when debugging.