# Embed different build of frameworks based on build target SDK

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using a third-party framework (Cronet) and wanted to embed different build/version of the framework (i.e. iOS simulator build vs. device build) based on Build Target SDK.

How can I specify it in Xcode, given the framework name will be the same, but only in different directory (`Debug-iphonesimulator/` . vs `Debug-iphoneos/`).

I tried to add both versions into Xcode `Build Phases` -> `Embed Frameworks`, but the build will fail and complains duplicates, so I had to pick only one. (See picture).

Btw, I wanted to use just one Target instead of two Targets for two builds.

[image]

Comment: just want to clarify,  this question is different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54891677/embed-different-framework-based-on-build-configuration  because I am trying to using the same framework different versions,  not different frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge simulator and iphone framework binaries into one binary file using `lipo` tool:

```
lipo "path/to/simulator/framework/Cronet.framework/Cronet" "path/to/iphone/framework/Cronet.framework/Cronet" -create -output "path/to/output/framework/Cronet.framework/Cronet"
```

Then copy any of Cronet.framework, replace binary `Cronet` with newly created by `lipo` file.
After this you can use this framework in both targets: simulator and iphone

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I didn't want to include both versions of the frameworks all the time, i.e. hoping to include only the version needed.